# SVG not displaying elements added via d3 & jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg, dc.js

I have a line chart created via d3. For each datapoint (svg circle element), I am appending a sibling  element using d3 & jquery.  The elements do get created and added correctly, however they are not appearing.  If I edit the HTML block in Chrome Dev tools, the text elements do suddenly appear - as if the SVG object needed to be refreshed first to display the elements I appended.

Here is the code I use to insert my text elements:

```
        chart.selectAll('circle.dot').each(
            function(){
                var thisCircle = $(this);
                var myText = document.createElement('text')
                $(myText).attr("x", +800)
                $(myText).attr("y", +200);
                $(myText).attr("fill", "red");
                $(myText).attr("font-family", "verdana");
                $(myText).text("testing");
                $(myText).attr("style", "font-weight:bold;z-index:100");

                this.parentNode.insertBefore(myText, this.nextSibling);
            }
        )
```

Is there a way to redraw or refresh the svg, or even better, make it update as I am appending the nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This mix of D3 and jQuery is not only unnecessary, but also it can make things fail silently. Besides that, there is an idiomatic D3 way to do what you are doing here. So, I advise you to refactor all this code. However, have in mind that here I'll only answer your main question (*"SVG not displaying elements"*), nothing more, nothing less. For your secondary question (*"Is there a way to redraw or refresh the SVG?"*) I suggest that you post a new question, with a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

That being said, let's see what's happening:

The problem in your code is that you are using `createElement`. Since this is an SVG, you have to use [createElementNS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElementNS), which:

> Creates an element with the **specified namespace URI** and qualified name. (emphasis mine)

The valid namespace URI for SVG is: `http://www.w3.org/2000/svg`

Therefore, it should be:

```
var myText = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "text")
```

Here is a simple demo with that change only:

```js
d3.selectAll('circle').each(
  function() {
    var thisCircle = $(this);
    var myText = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'text')
    $(myText).attr("x", 10)
    $(myText).attr("y", 70);
    $(myText).attr("fill", "red");
    $(myText).attr("font-family", "verdana");
    $(myText).text("testing");
    $(myText).attr("style", "font-weight:bold;z-index:100");

    this.parentNode.insertBefore(myText, this.nextSibling);
  }
)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="10" fill="teal"></circle>
  <circle cx="150" cy="50" r="10" fill="teal"></circle>
  <circle cx="250" cy="50" r="10" fill="teal"></circle>
</svg>
```